# confused category in objective-c concept

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, categories

hi i'm wondering category in objective-c

i have 3 files

1. A_ViewController
2. A_ViewController+Category
3. B_ViewController

here's example code

1-1. A_ViewController.h

```
@interface A_ViewController {
// some instance Variables
}
//some public methods
@end
```

1-2 A_ViewController.m

```
#import "A_ViewController.h."
@implementation A_ViewController
// implementation public methods and private methods
@end
```

2-1. A_ViewController+Category.h

```
@interface A_ViewControler(Category)
-(void) categoryMethod;
@end
```

2-2. A_ViewController+Category.m

```
#import "A_ViewController.h"
#import "A_ViewController+Category.h"
@implementation A_ViewController(Category)
-(void) categoryMethod {
     NSLog(@"it's A_ViewController+Category");
}
@end
```

3-1. B_ViewController.h

```
@interface B_ViewController {
// some instance variables
}
-(void) myMethod;
```

3-2. B_ViewController.m

```
#import "B_ViewController.h"
#import "A_ViewController.h"
@interface A_ViewController() // i think it's A_ViewController extension, not A_ViewController+Category, am i right?
-(void) categoryMethod;
@end
@implementation B_ViewController
-(void) myMethod
{
     A_ViewController *obj = [[A_ViewController alloc] init];
     [obj categoryMethod];
}
@end
```

i thought it's crashed because i'm not import A_ViewController+Category.h

and i'm not implement `-(void) categoryMethod` in B_ViewController.m

but it works fine, and no warning.

how `[obj categoryMethod]` can be linked??

if that's perfectly fine syntax, i have extension question.

if i have another category called A_ViewController+Category2

here's A_ViewController+Category.h

```
@interface A_ViewController(Category2)
-(void) categoryMethod;
@end
```

and A_ViewController+Category2.m

```
#import "A_ViewController.h"
#import "A_ViewController+Category2.h"
@implementation A_ViewController(Category2)
-(void) categoryMethod
{
    NSLog(@"it's A_ViewController+Category2");
}
@end
```

and this situation, if i write a code like 3-2,

then `[obj categoryMethod]` can' be guaranteed

that comes from A_ViewController+Category or A_ViewController+Category2, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling slightly to work out what you're trying to do but in regard to standard category behaviour.

If you want to call `categoryMethod` on an instance of `A_ViewController` from within `B_BiewController` you need to import the header that contains the category method @interface.

You can't declare the private category `()` on `A_ViewController` from within `B_ViewController.m`, as the private category or class extension is a special category.

**B_ViewController.m should look like this**

```
#import "B_ViewController.h"
#import "A_ViewController+Category.h"

@implementation B_ViewController

- (void) myMethod {
  A_ViewController *obj = [[A_ViewController alloc] init];
  [obj categoryMethod];
}

@end
```

**Edit**

I've just noticed your `Category2` method name is the same as your `Category` method name. This is incorrect and undefined behaviour in Objective C.

Comment: i was thought like you before 2 days a go, but i saw a code like my question yesterday, so i have a question..

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly, but I don't fully understand the question as Categories are quite straight forward, and selectors on categories shouldn't be identical.